# Prove that $B=\{z \in \mathbb{C}; 0<\operatorname{Im}(z) \le 1\}$ is not an open set.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, complex-numbers

I have written a solution for this question but I am unsure if it is right or wrong, and what should be fixed in case it is not.

1. Suppose that $B$ is open. Then, every disk $D(w,δ) = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid \lvert z-w \rvert < δ \}$ is contained in $B$. This is the same as saying that, if a belongs to $D$, it belongs to $B$;
2. If $w$ belongs to $B$, then $0< \operatorname{Im}(w) \le 1 $;
3. $\lvert \operatorname{Im}(a)-\operatorname{Im}(w) \rvert = \sqrt{(\operatorname{Im}(a)-\operatorname{Im}(w))^2} \le \sqrt{(\operatorname{Re}(a)-\operatorname{Re}(w))^2+(\operatorname{Im}(a)-\operatorname{Im}(w))^2)} = \lvert a-w \rvert < δ;$
4. Choose $δ=\operatorname{Im}(w) \Rightarrow 0<\operatorname{Im}(a)<2\operatorname{Im}(w)$.
   However, if $0<\operatorname{Im}(a) \leq 1$, then you can guarantee $\operatorname{Im}(a)>0$, but not that $\operatorname{Im}(a) \le 1$. Then, $a$ does not belong to $B$.

Thus, $B$ is not open.

Is this right? Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Formatting note:  type `\{` to get $\{$

Comment: 1.  is not true. If every disk is contained in $B$ then you much have $B= \mathbb{C}$. You pulled $a, \delta$ out of thin air in 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're quoting in sentence 1 is incorrect. $B$ is open if *for all* $w \in B$ *there exists* $\delta$ such that $D(w,\delta) \subseteq B$.

Flipping this around, $B$ is *not* open if *there exists* $w \in B$ such that *for all* $\delta$ , $D(w,\delta) \not\subseteq B$.

That is to say, $B$ is not open if you can find some $w \in B$ such that for all $\delta$ there exists $z$ such that $|z-w|<\delta$ but $z \notin B$.

There are many options for $w$; $i$ can't say which is my favorite.

To expand (in response to the comment), here is a new outline:

1. $B$ is not open if there exists $w \in B$ such that for all $\delta$ there exists $z$ such that $|z-w|<\delta$ but $z \notin B$.
2. Let $w = ...$ *You have to choose a good candidate. $i$ have given you two hints already.*
3. Given $\delta > 0$, let $z = ...$ *This $z$ should depend explicitly on $\delta$.*
4. *Show that $|z - w| < \delta$ and that $z \notin B$.*

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I substitute my first statement for yours, will the rest of the solution be right?

Comment: @soldaluz No. In step 2 you reference a generic $w$; like I said you need to be specific here. In step 3 you reference an unquantified variable $a$. In step 4 you reference a specific $\delta$, but as above you need to work with a generic one. I will expand my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Matthew Leingang has already provided you with a good answer, so I'll provide an alternative solution to the problem.

To show that $B$ is not open, we show that

$$\Omega=\mathbb{C}\setminus B=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\operatorname{Im}(z)\leq 0\text{ or }\operatorname{Im}(z)>1\}$$

is not closed. Consider the sequence $\{z_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{Z}^+}$ given by $z_j=\frac{j+1}{j}i$. Then $\operatorname{Im}(z_j)=\frac{j+1}{j}>1$, so the sequence is in $\Omega$. Furthermore the sequence is convergent with limit $i$. Now if $\Omega$ was closed, then this limit would also have to be in $\Omega$, however clearly $i\notin\Omega$, and so $\Omega$ is not closed. It follows that $B$ is not open.